# How do i remove a nextline symbol # from its output in java?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, lexical-analysis

I've been creating a lexical analyzer and everything works fine, except, I don't want the output to  include a nextline "#" in the console. How can I do this ?

```
 Token getToken() {
    int line, pos;
    while (Character.isWhitespace(this.chr)) {
        getNextChar();
    }
    line = this.line;
    pos = this.pos;

    switch (this.chr) {
        case '\u0000': return new Token(TokenType.End_of_input, "", this.line, this.pos);
        case '\'': return char_lit(line, pos);
        case '<': return follow('=', TokenType.less_than_operator, TokenType.less_than_operator, line, pos);
        case '=': return follow('=', TokenType.Assignment_operator, TokenType.Assignment_operator, line, pos); 
        case '"': return string_lit(this.chr, line, pos);
        case '{': getNextChar(); return new Token(TokenType.Opening_brace, "", line, pos);
        case '}': getNextChar(); return new Token(TokenType.Closing_brace, "", line, pos);
        case '(': getNextChar(); return new Token(TokenType.Opening_parenthesis, "", line, pos);
        case ')': getNextChar(); return new Token(TokenType.Closing_parenthesis, "", line, pos);
        case ';': getNextChar(); return new Token(TokenType.Semi_colon, "", line, pos);
        case ',': getNextChar(); return new Token(TokenType.Comma, "", line, pos);
        case '#': getNextChar(); return new Token(TokenType.Nextline, "", line, pos);
        case '□': getNextChar(); return new Token(TokenType.Space_separator, "", line, pos);
        default: return identifier_or_integer(line, pos);
    }
}
```

This code gets the tokens

```
void printTokens() {
    Token t;
    System.out.println("Lexical Analyzer ");
    System.out.println("-----------------");
    while ((t = getToken()).tokentype != TokenType.End_of_input) {
        //except nextline
        System.out.println(t);

    }
    System.out.println(t-);
}
```

This code prints out the output

Comment: Have you tried to put a simple `if` before the `System.out.println`? `if (t.tokentype == TokenType.Nextline) continue;`

Comment: i tried that inside the while loop , got an error . let me try that outside the while.

Comment: It should be inside the loop. Please show the code which you tried and the exact error message.

Comment: @Alex it actually works inside the loop , thanks .

Comment: check for '\n' in the switch